# WPF style like CSS

Tags: wpf, styles, wpf-controls

Here is my situation:

> We use 3rd party control, and due to the bad design of this control, we need to modify its visual tree child(element `Path`) style. Only one thing we have known is the child's name.

If WPF has the similar mechanism as CSS, we can simply finish that like:

```
#PathName { ... }
```

What's the equivalent way in WPF that can use element name to define the style?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Please post the relevant XAML or at least a screenshot of what you have versus what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set style of a control through code behind like this

```
myTextBlock.SetResourceReference(TextBlock.StyleProperty, "MyStyle")
```

or like this

```
Style style = this.FindResource("LabelTemplate") as Style;
```

myTextBlock.Style = style;